# C++: Is memcpy to POD based sub-object UB?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, malloc, language-lawyer

Let's go to the code:

```
extern "C" {
#include "pod-struct-T.h"
#include "malloc-and-initialize-one-T.h"
}

struct TCpp : T
{
   TCpp()
   {
      T* ptr_t = malloc_and_initialize_one_T();
      T* this_t = static_cast<T*>(this);
      std::memcpy(this_t, ptr_t, sizeof(T));
      free(ptr_t);
   }
};
```

How many UBs is there in this piece of code (for both C++03 and C++11; or for C++20 if something has change after its revisited memory model) or doing that `memcpy` is just fine? In case it is UB, is it at least portable among major compilers? (gcc, clang, intel, etc).

**DISCLAIMER**: Yes I know..., it's ugly, but don't ask why I need to do this.

Comment: The only UB in this code would be if `malloc_and_initialize_one_T()` returns a NULL pointer, which you are not checking for, or if `T` has non-POD members or pointer members. Aside from that, you don't need the `static_cast` at all, `T* this_t = this;` works just fine since `TCpp` derives from `T`.

Comment: I agree with @RemyLebeau. AFAICT the `static_cast`, `memcpy`, and `free` are all safe as long as there aren't any gotchas with `ptr_t`. That is, `malloc_and_initialize_one_T` returns a properly aligned + sized, nonnull, `T*` and `T` is actaully a POD.

Comment: @LeoCHan `T` can be a POD and still have problems copying into it, ie if it contains members that are pointers, which are themselves POD, or references.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Actually, the "POD" structure do contain pointers in my case, but that situation is totally managed.

Comment: Memcpying into potentially-overlapping subobjects (including base-class subobjects) is definitely not allowed, due to potential padding reuse.

Comment: @Peregring-lk `memcpy`'ing a structure that contains pointers is a recipe for disaster. It would really help if you would show what `T` actually looks like, and what `malloc_and_initialize_one_T()` actually does with `T`

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, I haven't thought about padding reuse, but makes total sense that those kind of optimizations do exist. However, if I make sure that every data member of the derived class is set after the memcpy to base-class suboject, there shoudn't be no problems right?

Comment: @RemyLebeau `T` is actually not a single type. It's a family of POD-types that are automatically generated by a "script" (each type represent the contents of a network message). Each type also comes with a set of functions for coding and decoding the message. So I provide a macro that generates a class that derives from the type whose name is the message name that is passed to the macro argument. These functions, that also contains the message name, are automatically generated based,, called and used in the appropiated function members: constructors, destructors, send members, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The pointers are also automatically created and pulled by the "creation functions", but also destructed by the "destruction functions". In practical means, for me are just wrappers for a set of mallocs and free that are called in my macro-class in constructor/destructor and so copy the pointer to the base-class subobject is just copy what malloc returns. If the user wants to inherit from the automatically-generated class to add customized behaviour, he knows that he doesn't own the memory of the inner pointers so I don't see the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is pretty unambiguous. [[basic.types]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.types#3) (emphasis added, footnote omitted):

> For any trivially copyable type `T`, if two pointers to `T` point to
>   distinct `T` objects `obj1` and `obj2`, *where neither `obj1` nor `obj2` is a
>   potentially-overlapping subobject*, if the underlying bytes
>   ([intro.memory]) making up `obj1` are copied into `obj2`, `obj2` shall
>   subsequently hold the same value as `obj1`.

[Base-class subobjects are potentially-overlapping subobjects.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#7.1) It follows that the standard doesn't define what the resulting value is if you `memcpy` into a base-class subobject.

What's wrong with simple assignment?

Comment: Yes I don't know why I didn't think of simple assignment when the behaviour is completely defined. I've changed that now in my implementation, thanks. I guess my mind was in a "low-level programming mode" and I missed the big picture.

Comment: And I guess `memcpy` to a base-class subobject is just ill-formed, because there's no rule that explicitly allows doing that nor stating it as UB.

Comment: @Peregring-lk The term "ill formed" is for code that either must be diagnosed by the compiler, or can cause the compiler to reject the code w/ a diagnostic, but doesn't have to, like a missing function definition (compiler never reject programs for a missing non virtual function definition, but they could). Doing illegal things at runtime by definition is not diagnosable.